# Group By SQL Statement - consolidating results on one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have created a database table called tbl_timesheet_hours as follows:

```
timesheet_no
work_order_no
work_order_date
work_order_hours
```

with data populated in the table as:

```
timesheet_no    work_order_no   work_order_date     work_order_hours
4               NTS0026B        2012-01-02          1
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-02          9
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-03          8
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-04          7
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-05          6
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-06          5
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-07          4
4               NTS0031B        2012-01-08          3
```

I need to create a query which will form the basis for a time sheet report which can be printed in a typical contractor's time sheet format, i.e, it will show the work_order_no field in the first column, followed by hours allocated for each day. The query I have created is:

```
SELECT
  work_order_no,
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Mon", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Mon],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Tue", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Tue],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Wed", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Wed],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Thu", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Thu],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Fri", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Fri],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Sat", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Sat],
  switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Sun", SUM(work_order_hours)) AS [Sun]
FROM tbl_timesheet_hours
WHERE timesheet_no=4
GROUP BY work_order_date, work_order_no;
```

The query produces the following result set,

```
work_order_no   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
NTS0026B         1                      
NTS0031B         9                      
NTS0031B             8                  
NTS0031B                 7              
NTS0031B                     6          
NTS0031B                         5      
NTS0031B                             4  
NTS0031B                                 3
```

Is it possible to restructure the query to produce the following result set?

```
work_order_no   Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
NTS0026B        1                       
NTS0031B        9   8   7   6   5   4   3
```

Any type of assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the data itself stored in ms-access or are you ms-access to work with a SQL-Server data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a Crosstab query as follows:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tbl_timesheet_hours.[work_order_hours]) AS SumOfwork_order_hours
SELECT tbl_timesheet_hours.[work_order_no], Sum(tbl_timesheet_hours.[work_order_hours]) AS     [Total Of work_order_hours]
FROM tbl_timesheet_hours
GROUP BY tbl_timesheet_hours.[work_order_no]
ORDER BY Format([work_order_date],'ddd')
PIVOT Format([work_order_date],'ddd') In ("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun");
```

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `SWITCH` expression *inside* `SUM()`? Like this:

```
SELECT
  work_order_no,
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Mon", work_order_hours)) AS [Mon],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Tue", work_order_hours)) AS [Tue],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Wed", work_order_hours)) AS [Wed],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Thu", work_order_hours)) AS [Thu],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Fri", work_order_hours)) AS [Fri],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Sat", work_order_hours)) AS [Sat],
  SUM(switch(Format(work_order_date,'ddd') = "Sun", work_order_hours)) AS [Sun]
FROM tbl_timesheet_hours
WHERE timesheet_no=4
GROUP BY work_order_no;
```

In addition to that, remove also `work_order_date` from `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Tried it. The resulting data set is the same as my original query.

Comment: @rosst400: Of course, I forgot to remove one entry from GROUP BY, sorry! Please try the updated version.